# Use alternative producers of EntityManager / EMF in integration tests

Tags: java, maven, jpa, integration-testing, cdi

I looking for way how to use CDI and alternative producers in integration tests. When i speak about producers, i mean EMF producer. Reason for different EMF producer is that i want to use testing in-memory database (different persistence unit).

Is there easy way how to start CDI for integrations test and use alternative producers?

Used technologies: Java EE, JPA, CDI ([weld](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/)), [DeltaSpike](https://deltaspike.apache.org/), based on [maven](http://maven.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research i found that DeltaSpike already has module called '[Test-Control](http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/test-control.html)', which enable use CDI in tests. So i decided to extend current EMF producer to read name of persistence unit from property file which contains configuration. Different property files in `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` lets me use different persistence unit for integration tests.